# Writing multiple html lines in php (echo)

Tags: php, html

can anyone help me please? :D

i'm new in php, i want to write multiple lines of html in php file using echo that what i did but it's doesn't work this is a code of vendor details (dokan ) and i wan't to display those blocks in order detail page:

```
    <div class="profile-img">
        <?php echo get_avatar( $author->ID, 90 ); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="dokan-store-info">
        <?php if ( !empty( $store_info['store_name'] ) ) : ?>
            <h4 class="store-name"><?php printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', dokan_get_store_url( $author->ID ), $store_info['store_name'] ); ?></h4>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="store-ratings">
            <?php dokan_get_readable_seller_rating( $author->ID ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="seller-name">
            <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Vendor:', 'multistore' ); ?></span>

            <span class="details">
                <?php printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', dokan_get_store_url( $author->ID ), $author->display_name ); ?>
            </span>

            <?php do_action( 'dokan_store_header_info_fields',  $author->ID ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php if ( !empty( $store_info['address'] ) ) : ?>
            <div class="store-address">
                <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                <address class="address"><?php echo dokan_get_seller_address( $author->ID ); ?></address>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( !empty( $store_info['phone'] ) ) : ?>
            <div class="store-phone">
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                <address class="phone"><?php echo ($store_info['phone']); ?></address>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="store-details">
            <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
            <?php printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', dokan_get_store_url( $author->ID ), esc_html__('View store', 'multistore') ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
```

Comment: sorry i forgot the echo ' in the first line

Comment: Use <br> each line...

Comment: redo all your code, and write it again line by line to while testing. Probably your have missing colon or open bracket

Comment: rewrite your code, execute it while writing line by line.

Comment: I'm seeing alot of php and calling to variable but I dont see where some of them are defined. If there is more code in this page that would be helpful

Comment: Hello @EthanMarley, welcome to StackOverflow. :-) Instead of stating that *"it doesnt work"*, please describe the problem you have as precise as possible, so we know what the acutal problem is that you are facing.

Comment: @AlexCarlson i use wordpress so...

Comment: Thanks for the replys
AlexCarlson i use wordpress so...
@PhilippMaurer when i add those lines i have php error in line where this code start, i can't copy the right message now i'll do it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finnaly i used an online tool to convert html to php and here is the right way:

```
echo '<div class="product-vendor-info">';
echo '<div class="profile-img">';
echo '<?php echo get_avatar( $author->ID, 90 ); ?>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="dokan-store-info">';
echo '<?php if ( !empty( $store_info['store_name'] ) ) : ?>';
echo '<h4 class="store-name"><?php printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', dokan_get_store_url( $author->ID ), $store_info['store_name'] ); ?></h4>';
echo '<?php endif; ?>';
echo '<div class="store-ratings">';
echo '<?php dokan_get_readable_seller_rating( $author->ID ); ?>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="seller-name">';
echo '<span><?php esc_html_e( 'Vendor:', 'multistore' ); ?></span>';
echo '';
echo '<span class="details">';
echo '<?php printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', dokan_get_store_url( $author->ID ), $author->display_name ); ?>';
echo '</span>';
echo '';
echo '<?php do_action( 'dokan_store_header_info_fields',  $author->ID ); ?>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<?php if ( !empty( $store_info['address'] ) ) : ?>';
echo '<div class="store-address">';
echo '<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>';
echo '<address class="address"><?php echo dokan_get_seller_address( $author->ID ); ?></address>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<?php endif; ?>';
echo '<?php if ( !empty( $store_info['phone'] ) ) : ?>';
echo '<div class="store-phone">';
echo '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>';
echo '<address class="phone"><?php echo ($store_info['phone']); ?></address>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<?php endif; ?>';
echo '<div class="store-details">';
echo '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>';
echo '<?php printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', dokan_get_store_url( $author->ID ), esc_html__('View store', 'multistore') ); ?>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```